# Vite proxy server after build does not work

Tags: reactjs, vite

I know that proxy server config on vite.config.ts is just suposed to work only in dev server.But is there any way to make a proxy service in a react vite project?
What I need is that, some how, after the build my proxy server to work. Running locally before the build works fine.
Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

```
server: {
      host: config.host,
      port: config.port,
      base: config.base,
      proxy: {
        '/broker': {
          target: env.VITE_REACT_APP_TARGET_BROKER,
          changeOrigin: true,
          rewrite: path => path.replace('/broker', ''),
          secure: false,
        },
      },
    },
```